# Are satellites orbiting around earth visible to the naked eye?

Tags: amateur-observing, observational-astronomy, satellite

I was just lying under the sky trying to possibly see some meteorites, unfortunately never seeing any I might add, but I saw three objects all moving at about the same speed( all at different times). They were far too faint and small to be aircraft or anything inside of the atmosphere I would think and there were no blinking lights. They were also moving fairly quickly it seemed. Could these have been satellites in low earth orbit? It's the only other thing I would think that they could be.

Answer (score 16):

A lot of satellites are visible under the right conditions. Usually up to 2 hours after sunset and 2 hours before sunrise. This allows the sun to strike the satellite when you are on the dark side. Depending on the orbit, it will take between 1 and 5 minutes to traverse most of the sky. Usually, they will enter the shadow and you lose sight of them.

Comment: I would say timing is pretty spot on here. I've noticed them many times before and always wondered if that's what they were.

Comment: Have a look at [Spot the ISS](http://spotthestation.nasa.gov/home.cfm) and [See Iridium Flares](http://www.heavens-above.com/) for times to see satellites.

Comment: There are also smartphone apps that allow you to predict when you can spot the ISS passing above your place. Also Iridium flare predictor apps. Yes, those moving dots you've seen are reasonably likely satellites (can't say 100% sure, but fairly likely).

Comment: I like this link for the ISS better: http://iss.astroviewer.net/observation.php